# facebook php pi fanned_pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'd like to obtain a list of pages liked by a page
using Facebook php api but I can't find how to do it.

You can obtain this info if you know the id of a page:
https://www.facebook.com/browse/fanned_pages/?id=11...5

I've searched here but there's no mention to fanned_pages:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
/{page_id}/likes
```

and **not**

```
/{page_id}?fields=likes
```

Compare the output of the CocaCola page

```
https://www.facebook.com/browse/fanned_pages/?id=40796308305
```

vs.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=40796308305%2Flikes&version=v2.4
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/likes/#Reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/object/likes

Comment: It seems wrong. If you check [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page) likes is the number of users who liked the page.
  
This returns numbers:
`$pageResp = $fb->get('/'.$page[id].'?fields=likes');
$pageNode = $pageResp->getGraphObject();
$pageNode->asArray();`

Comment: *What* "seems wrong"? There is no such thing as "fanned pages" in the Graph API, it's called `likes`. Please be more specific!